# Why would one core of a quad-core CPU run much hotter than the other three?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

[image: Close up of Core Temp reported CPU Core temeratures]

This is a 2010 vintage system (HP DV7 17.3" laptop) with a first generation core i7 Q720 M.

I recently replaced the heat sink compound with new Arctic Silver when temperatures were going above 200F and triggering a shutdown.

After several months it has started showing one core much hotter at times - core 3 (of 0 .. 3).

I'm wondering if the heat sink compound is not evenly distributed.

Comment: It might be the thermal compound, but it could also be an application running in  a single thread that uses the full time of one core, e.g. Brutal Chess, which uses only 11% of my PC's CPU but heats one processor sufficiently to turn on the fan. Check Task Manager. Also check that the fan is clean and unobstructed (e.g. cable over part).

Comment: I think that other cores don't feel good too. Usually it is time to replace heat sink compound. The only warning - DO NOT put too much compound, it should be very thin layer that only cover micro bumps. Use a good compound as arctic silver or similar.

Comment: Your processor nor one of the cores is running at 200 F.  That is well above the thermal limits of the processor

Comment: The thermal limit is specified as 100 C which is 212 F. So 200 F is not "well above" the thermal limits. But... it is too hot, for sure!

Comment: I redid the thermal compound about 10 weeks ago with carefully applied Arctic Silver. I used their cleaner to get rid of the old compound and put only a very thin layer per their instructions.

Before this, the CPU would heat up to over 200 F quickly and trigger a shutdown. Now it typically idles at about 160 F but I see this issue with the one core occasionally.